# Python IMAP Gmail Connection Error on Hosting Services but Works Locally

Tags: python-3.x, gmail-imap

I have a Python script that connects to Gmail using IMAP, which works perfectly in my local development environment in Visual Studio. However, when I try to run the same script on a hosting service (such as Namecheap), I encounter a network connectivity error.

The specific error I get is: `OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable`.

Here's a simplified version of my code (with sensitive details removed):

```py
import imaplib

# Connect to Gmail IMAP server
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('myemail@gmail.com', 'mypassword')
# ... rest of the code ...
```